# Rails - Users should have only one row of data in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, row, form-for

I want for every users to have only one row of data in a table named business. He can edit it for the second time.

Also i want to submit each column value separately using **form_for** but when i do like this when submitting the form for the second time for a different column entry, it goes to the second row making the previous row empty.

How can i achieve this?

Here is my code...

```
<%= form_for @new_business do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :first_problem %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

A screenshot of the data table

[Table data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8n4e.png)

Any help is appreciated as i am new to rails. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your code for your controller?  You should have a separate action for editing an object vs. creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

One user can only have one business, you need to set relationship between them

In user.rb model

```
has_one :business
```

In business.rb model

```
belongs_to :user
```

For your second problem, i think you are not passing row id for which you want to update columns, so everytime it is creating a new entry for that column

Comment: If i use has_one :business then for new business creation i have to use Business.new instead of current_user.businesses.new right?

Comment: However i have user validates :user_id uniqueness in business.rb so it will have only one entry for any users. Now how to pass the row id when submitting forms?

Comment: Yes, also you need to create a different action for updating columns, you can pass row id inside your form path helper, like `edit_path(row_id)` and inside your controller action, you can find that row by id, and update a particular column

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code snippet is from your new template (i.e. "app/views/businesses/new.html.erb").  This should only be used when you want a new object created.  Your controller probably says something like

```
def new
  @new_business = Business.new
end
```

When the form is submitted, the :create action in your controller gets called, which should create a new record in the database.

When you want to edit that object, you use an edit action in your controller that corresponds to an edit.html.erb view.  Something like this in the controller:

```
def edit
  @business = Business.find(params[:id])
end
```

with a similar form to the one you listed above in the view.  When that form is submitted, it should route to an :update action in your controller, that updates the existing record in the database.

The tricky part about what you are trying to accomplish is limiting each user to only being able to create one record in the database.  There are many ways to go about doing this, but the general idea would be to restrict the user's access to the new and create actions in the controller once they have already created a record.  You can do that by using before_action (if using Rails 4.0 or greater) or before_filter (if using Rails < 4.0) to call a method that checks if a user has already created a record.